# Pandas concat последовательное добавление данных в один столбец dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A','B'])
df['A']=np.random.randint(5,10,3) 
for i in range(3):
    temp =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,3), columns=['B'])
    df = pd.concat([df,temp], ignore_index= True)
print(df)
```

Получаем:

```
      A    B
0   9.0  NaN
1   7.0  NaN
2   6.0  NaN
3   NaN    2
4   NaN    1
5   NaN    1
6   NaN    2
7   NaN    4
8   NaN    2
9   NaN    4
10  NaN    2
11  NaN    4
```

Как сделать, чтобы при конкатенации в цикле столбец df['B'] последовательно заполнялся с начала столбца (с нулевого индекса), а не с того индекса где закончился столбец df['A']? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно еще так сделать:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A','B'])
df['A']=np.random.randint(5,10,3) 
for i in range(3):
    temp =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,3), columns=['B'])
    df = pd.concat([df,temp], ignore_index= True)
    df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
print(df)
```

df:

```
     A  B
0  9.0  2
1  9.0  2
2  5.0  1
3  NaN  2
4  NaN  1
5  NaN  3
6  NaN  1
7  NaN  4
8  NaN  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Не соображу, есть ли универсальное решение, но проще всего, наверное, в первый раз явно писать в столбец `B` данные, а дальше уже конкатенировать:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A','B'])
df['A']=np.random.randint(5,10,3) 
for i in range(3):
    temp =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,3), columns=['B'])
    if i == 0:
        df['B'] = temp['B']
    else:
        df = pd.concat([df,temp], ignore_index= True)
print(df)
```

Вывод:

```
     A  B
0  5.0  1
1  9.0  2
2  7.0  1
3  NaN  1
4  NaN  4
5  NaN  3
6  NaN  3
7  NaN  1
8  NaN  4
```